# Appium Automatic Server - No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '68.0.3440'

Tags: android, selenium-chromedriver, appium, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to connect a physical Android device to Appium Automatic Server.  The capabilities are:

```
{
  "platformName": "Android",
  "platformVersion": "8.1.0",
  "deviceName": "Oreo",
  "browserName": "Chrome"
}
```

When I click "Start Session" it says

```
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '68.0.3440'. See https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md for more details.
```

Going to https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md it says I need version 2.4.2.  I tried installing it with `npm install -g appium-chromedriver --chromedriver_version="2.42"`, is this not the right command?

I also tried downloading the zip here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/ and running it to no avail.

Comment: I had a lot of grief with this same kind of problem and never really resolved it.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

**Try the below commands if you are turning on Appium server from command prompt.**

```
npm install appium --chromedriver_version="2.42"

or 

CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=2.42 npm install appium
```

**If you are turning on appium server from Appium desktop app.**

Provide the path of the chromedriver binary in the highlighted field.

[image]

Comment: That’s great 

Answer (score 1):

When I had the same issue, I resolved it like this :

cd  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

1. npm uninstall appium
2. npm install appium --chromedriver_version="79.0.3945.36"

Answer (score 0):

After setting the Appium CrhomeDriver Binary path and trying the code, I got the same error.

However, when I add the following code then it is executed successfully:

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable","/Users/myUsername/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/chromedriver/mac/chromedriver");
```

Answer (score 0):

Chromedriver Binary Path in GUI Appium - it`s work for me!